# Segmentation Fault within but unsure how to fix

Tags: c, gdb

Currently trying to work on this code to find errors and how to fix them and learning how to use GDB for the first time,

```c
int Find11();
void PointersAreFun();

int main(void) {
  int myArray[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
  int found = Find11();
  if (found != -1) {
    printf("The number 11 is in the table at location: %d\n", found);
  } else {
    printf("The number 11 is not in the table.\n");
  }

  PointersAreFun(myArray, 10);
  return 0;
}

int Find11(void) {
  int i = 0;
  int count = 0;
  int search = 1;
  int found = -1;
  int number = 5;
  int table[10];

  table[0] = number;
  printf("table[%i]: %i\n", count, table[count]);

  count = 1;
  while (count < 10) {
    table[count] = number++ * 2;
    printf("table[%i]: %i\n", count, table[count]);
    count++;
  }
  while (search = 1) {
    if (table[i++] == 11) {
      search = 0;
      found = -1;
    }
    if (count == i) {
      search = 0;
      found = 0;
    }
  }
  return found;
}

void PointersAreFun(int myArray[], int size) {
  printf("\nDemo on Pointers!\n");
  int anotheArray[10] = {10, 11, 12};
  int *ptrArray = NULL;
  int *ptrAnotherArray = NULL;
  ptrArray = myArray;
  printf("The first value of the array is %d\n", *ptrArray);
  printf("The first value of the second array is %d\n", *ptrAnotherArray);
}
```

I've identified the segmentation fault around this block of code

```c
  while (search = 1) {
    if (table[i++] == 11) {
      search = 0;
      found = -1;
    }
    if (count == i) {
      search = 0;
      found = 0;
    }
  }
```

but I am unsure how to fix the problem as it appears that variable i continues to increment forever skipping the 
if( count == i)
as in the GDB debugger even if the count is 10 and variable i equals 10 it continues to increment. Skipping over the second if condition

Comment: What does ptrAnotherArray point to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your code:

```
while( search = 1 )
```

You have to use `==` to compare `search` to `1`

One more thing

```
int * ptrAnotherArray = NULL;
printf("The first value of the second array is %d\n", *ptrAnotherArray);
```

You set the pointer == `NULL` then you print the value that it points to. It makes segt fault